# Is it possible to store and retrieve a Type in appsettings?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, appsettings, asp.net-core-configuration

Is it possible to store a value of type `Type` in appsettings? (Also, that is a seriously hard question to search!)

I have a class like this, that I want to serialize and store in appsettings:

```
class MyClass{
    public Type StoredType {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I have serialized the object

```
var obj = new MyClass{
    Name = "A String",
    StoredType = typeof(String)
};

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

and stored it in appsettings:

```
"StoredClass" : {
    "StoredType" : "System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
    "Name" :  "A String"
}
```

When I try to load the object from the configuration, the `Name` field is populated, but `StoredType` is always null.

```
var configVal = _configuration.GetValue<MyClass>("StoredClass");

Assert.Equal(configVal.Name, "A String"); //passes
Assert.Equal(configVal.StoredType, typeof(String)); //fails
Assert.NotNull(configVal.StoredType); //fails
```

UPDATE: If I deserialize with Newtonsoft, it works, but configuration still doesn't.

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(serialized);

Assert.Equal(configVal.Name, "A String"); //passes
Assert.Equal(configVal.StoredType, typeof(String)); //passes
Assert.NotNull(configVal.StoredType); //passes
```

CONCLUSION:
@Sam Axe has a solution that works, and I ended up using it. I believe the reason for the problem is that `Type` is actually an abstract class. When we work with `Type` in code, the instance is usually a `RuntimeType`, which is a private class in the `System` namespace. So, it seems Newtonsoft is doing some trickery to deserialize this, but the JSON parser used by the Configuration library is not. It makes sense when you consider you can't actually deserialize a string to an abstract class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are outputting a string in the serialized text.  You will need some method of reconstituting the string into a Type.  There are many many methods of doing this.  Here's a quick and dirty method:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Type _myType = null;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Type MyType {get { return _myType; }   set { _myType = value; } }

    public String StoredType {  
        get { return _myType.ToString(); }     
        set { _myType = Activator.CreateInstance(value); }
    }

    public string Name { get;set; }
}
```

Comment: I suppose I could do this if I have to, but I'm not sure why something that was serialized in code wouldn't deserialize without help.